# breakpoints in shiny functions do not stop for debugging

Tags: r, shiny

The breakpoints I set in the functions in shiny do not stop as expected.

I have set the breakpoints, and run the commends debug() for all the nested functions.

Any ideas, please?
Thanks!
JX

Answer (score 1):

Breakpoints won't pause execution if the object they support is not visible, make sure the render, observer or reactive is being invalidated by the session.

If that doesn't work, stick a `browser()` where you'd like to break in.